# How to find the difference in two javascript arrays, which could have duplicates, in an order-preserving way

Tags: javascript, arrays, difference

I have a textarea for users to input a comma-separated list of keywords. They can presumably delete or change any works of the list, or add words, either via the keyboard or copy paste. Order matters in the list, and there can be duplicates, e.g. `apple, orange, strawberry, strawberry` might become `apple, orange, kiwi, strawberry, orange`.

I want to compute an account of the differences between such lists. For the example above, I would want a result like `[{2: 'strawberry'}, {2: 'kiwi', 4: 'orange'}]` ([removed, added], indexing into old and new lists). How do we know which strawberry was removed? How do we know the second orange was added? We can compute this "greedily", looking for similarity from left-to-right.

Comment: I think there are more complexities in here than you might realize.  You might want to look at the [Wagner-Fischer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm).

Comment: I think I'm going to open a bounty on this, to get some good javascripters to take a look.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 0):

My solution depends on underscore.js

It feels very bulky, but it works on everything I've thrown at it so far. I'd be interested if folks had suggestions on how to improve it.

```
let distance_to_x_from_i_in_a = (a, x, i) => _(a).indexOf(x, i) - i;

Array.prototype.slice_from_to = function(from, to) { return _.object(_.range(from, to), this.slice(from, to)); };

function uniques(a1, i1, a2, i2) {

    if (i1 === a1.length || i2 === a2.length) {

        return [[a1.slice_from_to(i1, a1.length),
                 a2.slice_from_to(i2, a2.length)]]; }

    else if (a1[i1] === a2[i2]) { return uniques(a1, i1+1, a2, i2+1); }

    else {
        distance_in_a1_to_a2_head = distance_to_x_from_i_in_a(a1, a2[i2], i1);
        distance_in_a2_to_a1_head = distance_to_x_from_i_in_a(a2, a1[i1], i2);

        a1_head_exists_in_a2 = distance_in_a2_to_a1_head > 0;
        a2_head_exists_in_a1 = distance_in_a1_to_a2_head > 0;

        if (!a1_head_exists_in_a2 && !a2_head_exists_in_a1) { return [[{[''+i1]:a1[i1]}, {[''+i2]:a2[i2]}]].concat(uniques(a1, i1+1, a2, i2+1)); }

        else if (a1_head_exists_in_a2 && !a2_head_exists_in_a1) { return [[{}, a2.slice_from_to(i2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)]].concat(uniques(a1, i1, a2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)); }

        else if (!a1_head_exists_in_a2 && a2_head_exists_in_a1) { return [[a1.slice_from_to(i1, i1+distance_in_a1_to_a2_head), {}]].concat(uniques(a1, i1+distance_in_a1_to_a2_head, a2, i2)); }

        else if (distance_in_a2_to_a1_head < distance_in_a1_to_a2_head) { return [[{}, a2.slice_from_to(i2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)]].concat(uniques(a1, i1, a2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)); }

        else if (distance_in_a1_to_a2_head < distance_in_a2_to_a1_head) { return [[a1.slice_from_to(i1, i1+distance_in_a1_to_a2_head), {}]].concat(uniques(a1, i1+distance_in_a1_to_a2_head, a2, i2)); }

        else if (distance_in_a1_to_a2_head === distance_in_a2_to_a1_head) { return [[{}, a2.slice_from_to(i2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)]].concat(uniques(a1, i1, a2, i2+distance_in_a2_to_a1_head)); }

        else { console.log('wtf'); }

    }
}

let uniqs = (a, b) => uniques(a, 0, b, 0).reduce((acc, [from_a1, from_a2]) => [Object.assign(acc[0], from_a1), Object.assign(acc[1], from_a2)], [{}, {}]);
```